# TV-Show: Time travel with group of different times. Fork-like tool used as weapon

Tags: identify-this-tv-show, time-travel

I saw this TV-show in the '80s. I scarcely remember a thing.
There was a group of people of different times traveling together across time.

Here are two characters that I remember:

FORK-GUY:
A man in the group (I think he was the up-most in the future) 
had a fork-like object that he used as a multi-purpose tool and weapon.
This man looked like the one in this picture:

[image: Lookalike of "fork-guy"]

WILLANWELL:
There was another guy called "Willanwell" (spanish version)
I searched that name on Internet and... nothing, so I guess I don't know the right spelling. I remember quite well the name, and it was not a spanish name.

I remember the episode where Willanwell was recruited by the group.
He was an expert of artificial intelligence. The FORK-GUY knew Willanwell's fame in the future. Willanwell had built many human-like robots. In that episode two of his robots (male and female) fell in love for each other and became a thread to Willanwell's control. He got angry and erased their memories. But when the two reprogrammed robots saw each other again, they remembered their love and Willanwel could not believe his eyes.

Comment: I'd say it's _Doctor Who_, except he used [a spoon](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DnedB2-WoTM).

Comment: I remember that one!

Comment: Who's the guy in the picture of the question? Has anybody noticed it?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is [The Fantastic Journey](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0075503/). It's actually from the late 70s rather than the 80s. The show revolves round a group of people shipwrecked or lost on an island in the Bermuda Triangle where different timezones are intermingled and interact. The main cast travel from place to place, trying to get home. It was cancelled after a single series of 10 episodes.

The "fork guy" is named Varian. He's played by Jared Martin (that's a picture from the series below). He used the device which looked a little like a tuning fork as a mental power amplifier. He was from the 23rd century and brought the device with him from there.

[image: Jared Martin in the Fantastic Journey]

The other person you're thinking of is Dr. Jonathan Willoway who was played by Roddy McDowell. He is encountered in episode 3, Beyond the Mountain where he is the master of a community of robots.

Comment: Thanks for the help. 
I've just seen the episode 3 (Beyond the Mountain) 
and realised there weren't two robots falling in live for each other,
but a robot for a human.
Thank you very much.

Comment: @SergioCruzCamposJiménez You can also upvote the answer if it is helpful. It is the Stackexchange way of saying thanks. :)

Comment: As I recall, he insists that he is an android, not a robot (which are non-sentient).